# MkDocs - how to create Table Of Contents from mkdocs.yml inside index.md

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I am looking for a way to automatically include TOC within `.md` files. This sounds like something trivial and was available in GitBook and other static website generators for ages.

Is there any extension supporting it?

Answer (score 4):

Out-of-the-box, no, MkDocs provides no way to pass any information into the Markdown text of a page. However, that could be possible with a [plugin](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/plugins/). You can find a list of known plugins [here](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/wiki/MkDocs-Plugins). Unfortunately, it does not appear that any plugins on that list pass the global navigation to the Markdown text of a page. However, the [markdownextradata](https://github.com/rosscdh/mkdocs-markdownextradata-plugin) and [macros](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin) plugins would be a good place to start as they both pass other information to the Markdown text.

For completness, note that MkDocs has both global Navigation and a table of contents. I'm assuming you are speaking of the global navigation as you indicate if should come from `index.yml`. In contrast, a TOC is page specific. Each page has its own TOC which is the list of headings on that page alone. MkDocs makes use of the [TOC](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/toc/) extension to Python-Markdown, which includes support for inserting a page-specific TOC into the page. Simply insert the text `[TOC]` on a line by itself anywhere in the Markdown text and the TOC will be inserted there.